# What is the micro-sd slot speed on the new Lumias?

Tags: micro-sd, lumia-550

I want to know what is the micro-sd slot speed on the Lumia 550? That is so I can buy the fastest sd for it without spending more for speed that the phone won't be able to handle.

Is it rated UHS 1? UHS 3? something else? These are minimum speeds. But any information is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think that beyond speed, you need to consider the cluster size when formating the SD Card (using exFAT). The cluster size has an important role.

I have a Extreme SD Card, and only performs well when I am using clusters bigger than default (32Kb), but not big enough (256Kb).